# Turning off the output bold text format

Tags: java, formatting

How can I turn the boldness of text output in Java?

Hey, I've been just trying some thing around in Java, trying to use bold text output in Java. I've succeded in implementing the boldness, but now I don't know how to turn it off.

If I for example have 2 different String that I want to print out. One is bold and the second one isn't. How can I do that?
Here's my code:

```
public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("\u001B[1mText");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Text");
    }
}
```

What I want to do here, is to have the top one bold and the lower one not bold. How can I achieve that? Or is there any simplier way of making the output Bold?

Comment: You may want to use `u001b[0m` to reset the output.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer! It is quite simple, but completely different.

```
public static final String ANSI_BOLD = "\u001B[1m";
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
```

First off, I just declare these two Strings. One acts like the Boldness enabler and the second one is a format reseter.

Then it's just a simple String building:

```
System.out.print(ANSI_BOLD + "Test" + ANSI_RESET);
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("Text");
```